# Getting a variable total price to the thank you page

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I'm creating a sweetshop for my apprenticeship project and its all working great except for one thing. i need to get my variable with the total price to the thank you page and I don't know tones of javascript but this is how I'm trying to do it:

Basket page:

```
    <p>Delivery fee: £2.50</p>
<p id="pricetotal">Price Total: £<?php echo $pricetotal; ?></p>

<script>
  
  document.cookie = "zzz_" + $pricetotal + "; ;path=/";
  
</script>
```

Thank you page:

```
<?php foreach ( $_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
if ((strpos($key,"zzz_") !== false)) {

      <p><?= ($_COOKIE['zzz_'.$pricetotal]) . "<br>"; ?></p>
}

}
```

Just wondering if im almost there or far off?

[product website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJmSd.png)

[basket website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZAK7.png)

[thank you website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oZ90.png)

[product.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIYON.png)

[basket.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GgHG.png)

[Thank-you.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm4XI.png)

Comment: Have you tried that? did it work?

Comment: yeah ive tried it and the error is:
Undefined variable: pricetotal in Code/thesweeshop/thank-you.php on line 18

Comment: its saying Undefined index: zzz_ as-well

Comment: what should the variable `$pricetotal` be equal to in your mental model of the process?

Comment: Hey unfortunately theres no set price. but ive added images to my question now if that helps :)

Comment: the main focus is the basket code and thank you code

Comment: Sorry, `$pricetotal` is the actual numerical value? Then this command: `$_COOKIE['zzz_'.$pricetotal]` would be `$_COOKIE['zzz_29.99']`, for example, which wouldn't make sense, because the whole point in storing the cookie would be to get the value `29.99` OUT of the cookie. But you'd have to have the value `29.99` already to request the value of the cookie.

Comment: you want to set the cookie in a way where you can do something like `$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]`, where `$cookie_name` is a value like `"price_total"`, not a string that can change to be anything.

Comment: Hmm im not really sure how to do that haha, any suggestions?

Comment: You just gotta go back and start researching how cookies work from scratch. What is a cookie? How does a server set a cookie? How does a client set a cookie (javascript-side)? Are client-side cookies stored server side? If not, what do I need to do to send a value from my client side to my server side so that my server knows of its value?

Comment: If you just focus on the fundamentals of what cookies are and how they work, the rest of your problem will end up solved.

Comment: Thanks for your help TKoL and will do.